# retrieve data from c# linq object to json to html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, getjson

Retrieve code from json.

C#code:-

```
var collection = getsortcat.Select(x => new
        {
            idterm = x.IDTerm,
            mvo = x.MVO,
            pic = x.Pic,
            said = x.SAid,
            termactive = x.TermActive,
            vid = x.Vid,
            fvo = x.FVO,
            eterm = x.ETerm,
            edef = x.EDef,
            buse = x.BUse,
            bterm = x.BTerm,
            idcat = x.TermCat,
            items = x.TermCategory1.IDCat,
            catname = x.TermCategory1.TermCategory1
        });
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string output = jss.Serialize(collection);
        return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Javascript Code:-

```
success: function (e) {
                    var txt = "'{ data :" + e + "}'";
                    var obj = eval("(" + txt + ")");
                    $('#pdata').append(obj.data[0]);
                },
```

Not getting output. Please give me solution how to retrieve data from c# linq object to json to html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix your controller action to get rid of any JavaScriptSerializers and manual plumbing code. Directly return the collection to the Json result:

```
var collection = getsortcat.Select(x => new
{
    idterm = x.IDTerm,
    mvo = x.MVO,
    pic = x.Pic,
    said = x.SAid,
    termactive = x.TermActive,
    vid = x.Vid,
    fvo = x.FVO,
    eterm = x.ETerm,
    edef = x.EDef,
    buse = x.BUse,
    bterm = x.BTerm,
    idcat = x.TermCat,
    items = x.TermCategory1.IDCat,
    catname = x.TermCategory1.TermCategory1
});
return Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now inside the success callback the `e` parameter already represents an array of objects that were parsed. You don't need to call any `eval`. Directly access the elements (by index) and then the properties:

```
success: function (e) {
    var txt = e[0].mvo;
},
```

you could also loop through the elements:

```
success: function (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        var element = e[i];
        alert(element.idterm);
    }
},
```